# Forming a branch target

Tags: assembly, mips

I was asked the following question:

"Given the following machine code instruction for a conditional branch:

0x15090002

How much is added to the PC of the branch to form the branch target?"

I'm new to assembly and I find this a little confusing. Isn't it supposed to be 6? PC+4+2 (from the immediate field in the instruction)?

Comment: Please add your target architecture in your question.

Comment: I'm using MIPS if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

From

> MIPS32TM Architecture For Programmers
> Volume II: The MIPS32TM Instruction Set

Instruction:

> Branch on Not Equal
>
> An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of the instruction following
> the branch (not the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address.

In other words, branch offsets are counted in (32-bit/**4**-byte-hence shifted by 2) *instructions*, starting with the instruction *immediately following* the branch-instruction. Therefore, your instruction will skip over the next two instructions, if the two tested registers are not equal.